# Quartz.Net 3.0 and IoC

Tags: c#, async-await, quartz.net, topshelf

So far I have TopShelf and Quartz.NET 2.6.x running in production just fine.

As I go through and Async/Await my "service" layer, my scheduler still needs to do something like this.

```
 Task.Execute().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I would like to take advantage of Quartz.NET 3.0, however, I have yet to find a way to make it work with TopShelf/Structuremap/Ect.

Has anyone else come across such an issue?